# approve is required in ERC20 for a Dex?

Tags: solidity

According to the take advantage function, it is used to use your tokens in an external contract based on the permissions and the amount that you indicate

But:
When implementing an ERC20 is it necessary to implement approve? To use it on a Dex?
With the ethereum fees high enough to make a simple swap. If I don't implement it, what can happen?

Answer (score 1):

The approve function allows an external address to spend tokens from a specific address on its behalf. If you do not implement it, then transferFrom function will not work, since you always need to approve the token usage for an specific spender. Thus, the only way to transfer tokens will be calling the function 'transfer', which won't be accepted by a DEX. DEXes use the transferFrom function in order to interact with an address’s tokens on its behalf.

Comment: Apparently I see that it is necessary, but I have seen that the function is vulnerable, is there no other method to implement as a safeAproval?

Comment: Why is it vulnerable?

Comment: @Cazs the approval function doesn't have any vulnerabilities per se, what people call vulnerabilities of the approval function are user errors, like approving more that the real needs that ends in someone stealing tokens or the case when you don't have the decreaseApproval and the approved address spend the tokens before you defined the new approved amount and then when the second call to decrease the approval is minted the malicius user already spended the tokens and how approval was called again the malicious user can spend more funds

Comment: but this are most user errors, is like doing a transfer with the wrong amount and say that the transfer function is vulnerable

Answer (score 1):

Let's say Dex contract has a staking functionality:

```
function stakeTokens(uint256 _amount,address _token) public{
        require(_amount>0,"Amount must be more than 0");
    
        /*call transferFrom from erc20. transfer only works if it is being called from the wallet who owns the tokens. If we dont own the token we use transferFrom. We have to have abi to call the transferFrom. so we need IERC20 interface*/
        // In order to interact with a contract we need abi
        // IERC20(_token) initilaizes the contract
        IERC20(_token).transferFrom(msg.sender,address(this),_amount);
       // ... more logic down here
    }
```

`approve` is used to authorize the DEX to make transfers on behalf of the token owner up to the approved amount. How DEX contract will withdraw from your contract? You have to first give permission with `approve`